# Need to CreateLoop for ARIMA (p,d,q)

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I need to find a way to run a loop on ARIMA code across multiple files or within a data frame

This is for my thesis project i am working on. However; given the sample size - running the code one by one will be too tedious and time consuming. Is therea way I can get the below code to work in a loop format if I had all my observations in a data frame?

Or alternatively, how can I get it to read multiple files and run the same code automatically?

```
library(readxl)
X104485 <- read_excel("Wits Business School/Thesis/Trial 1/Pilot - Data Files/104485.xlsx")
library(forecast)
myts <- ts(X104485, start=c(2015, 1), end=c(2019, 5), frequency=12)
fit <- arima(myts, order=c(1, 1, 36))
fcast <- forecast(fit,31)
write.csv((fcast), file = "X104485.csv")
```

The code above works - I just need it to be efficient in running several iterations at a time.

Please help.

Comment: Is your series a multivariate time series or univariate?

Comment: How many series do you have?